# Laravel Breeze routes overlapping

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-breeze

I'm getting this error suddenly when trying to use anything to do with Breeze, like login and view account.

```
Declaration of App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController::update(App\Http\Requests\ProfileUpdateRequest $request): Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse must be compatible with App\Http\Controllers\Controller::update(Illuminate\Http\Request $request, $id)
```

**ProfileController.php**

```
/**
     * Update the user's profile information.
     */
    public function update(ProfileUpdateRequest $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        $request->user()->fill($request->validated());

        if ($request->user()->isDirty('email')) {
            $request->user()->email_verified_at = null;
        }

        $request->user()->save();

        return Redirect::route('profile.edit')->with('status', 'profile-updated');
    }
```

On the 'ProfileUpdateRequest $request' it's giving me this error also:

```
Declaration must be compatible with Controller->update(request: \Illuminate\Http\Request, id)
```

I've tried Googling to find anyone with a similar issue but I'm unable to. I've compared my routes file with the official Breeze docs to no avail.

Comment: Does your `App\Http\Controllers\Controller` class have an `update()` method? If so, why?

Comment: Yes, because that's my update function. I'm trying to follow the correct naming conventions as this has never been an issue.

Comment: Your `ProfileController` extends the `Controller` class, which makes it so that the `update()` method on the `ProfileController` must match the declaration that you used in the base `Controller`. You shouldn't be using the base `Controller` class to handle any requests. You should remove the `update()` method from the base `Controller` class.

Comment: I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Routing is not the issue here, you have probably defined an `update()` method in the base Controller.

Your `ProfileController` extends the base `Controller`. You have defined an `update()` method in both of these classes.

This makes it so that the declaration of the `update()` method in the `ProfileController` must match the declaration of the `update()` method in the base `Controller` class, because it extends it.

Looking at the error message in the post, we can compare the two declarations:

```
public function update(ProfileUpdateRequest $request): RedirectResponse {} // ProfileController
public function update(Illuminate\Http\Request $request, $id) {} // Controller
```

*The request class is not an issue here. Provided that the `ProfileUpdateRequest` extends the `Illuminate\Http\Request`* class.

Your `ProfileController` does not use an `$id` and defines a return type, thus the declaration is different from the class that it extends (`App\Http\Controllers\Controller`). This results in the error.

Your base `App\Http\Controllers\Controller` should not define any methods. It is merely there so you can extend it in your Controllers and get the functionality from it. Removing the `update()` method from the base `Controller` class will fix your error. You should not use the base `Controller` itself to handle requests, but create a new controller that extends the base one.